What is the difference between (this->*&A::main)(); and this->A::main(); in C++ when dealing with virtual functions?
I'm trying to understand the difference between two ways of calling a function in C++, especially when dealing with virtual functions. Here is a simple code example:
#include <iostream>

class A {
public: 
    virtual void main() {
        std::cout << "virtual void main of A" << std::endl; 
    }

    int fun() {
        std::cout << "fun function: " << (long long)((void*)&A::main) << std::endl; 
        
        // Member function pointer pointing to A::main
        auto ptr = &A::main; 
        
        // Using 'this' pointer to call the function pointer
        (this->*ptr)();  
        
        // Explicitly calling A::main without virtual mechanism
        this->A::main();
        return 0; 
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void main() override {
        std::cout << "virtual void main of B" << std::endl; 
    }
};

int main() {
    B* b = new B;  
    A* a = b; 
    
    b->fun(); 
    a->fun(); 
    
    delete b;
    return 0; 
}


Output:
fun function: 4205984
virtual void main of B
virtual void main of A
fun function: 4205984
virtual void main of B
virtual void main of A

I'm confused about why (this->*ptr)() and this->A::main() produce different results. Both seem to be accessing A::main, but the output suggests they behave differently. Could someone explain why (this->*ptr)() calls B::main() while this->A::main() calls A::main()? How does the virtual function mechanism affect these calls? What happens internally in terms of virtual table lookups or direct function calls?

Don't write code like this. In (this->*ptr)() you're using member function pointer which is not actually a pointer at all!

(long long)((void*)&A::main) is invalid.

Hunting for a duplicate proved challenging because others came from the viewpoint that one of the behaviors was correct and asked why the other behaved differently. Your question asks for an explanation of both forms of syntax, so maybe multiple duplicates would cover the question? (Or maybe someone else can find a more direct duplicate? I feel like I've seen this asked before from this viewpoint.)

FYI, using main as the name of member functions is bad form.  Coders are accustomed to there only being one main function.  Try a different name, or a thesaurus.

A call via member function pointer will call the final overrider of the virtual function that it points to, just like a normal direct member function call with unqualified name referring to the same member function would.
A member function call with a qualified name for the member function will not call the final overrider. It will instead call the function found by name lookup as if it wasn't virtual.
That's just how the language is specified.

Side note: (long long)((void*)&A::main) is ill-formed. If your compiler permits it without diagnostic, then it is not behaving standard-conforming. Whatever output it produces has no relevance to the program behavior.

Isn't (long long)((void*)&A::main) UB or implementation defined etc?

@user12002570 It is ill-formed. The cast to void* is already not possible by any cast.

auto ptr = &A::main; gives you a member function pointer to main (its type is void (A::*)()). It's not a raw function pointer, it stores something more like the offset of the vtable entry for main. When you call it on a B, it finds the overridden main there and calls that, just as if you'd done whatever->main().
this->A::main(), on the other hand, means what it looks like: call A::main on this, without thinking about whether it's been overridden.
